# Python (numpy) 2D and 3D array averaging of subgrid

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

Use Python to extract gridded atmospheric data at various levels and convert to netCDF <- COMPLETED

Use Python to find gridded data for region and then average that data over sub-grids (2x2) grids <- INCORRECT

I can get this to work in Octave/Matlab, but I would like to keep this all in Python. The problem is, I believe, in the indexing syntax and my inability to beat Python into submission with regards to indexing.

Data: 1D array of longitudes, latitudes and pressure levels. The longitdues have 49 elements, the latitudes have 13 elements and the levels have 12. The data that I am attempting to average is in the first instance a 2D matrix (13x49) and in the second instance a 3D matrix (shape=12x13x49).

```py
#DEFINE LARGE AREA OF GLOBLE
londim_g  = 49
latdim_g  = 13
lonmin_g  = 60
lonmax_g  = 180
latmin_g  = -60
latmax_g  = -30
dlat=dlon = 2.5
lats_g      = arange(latmin_g,latmax_g+dlon,dlon)
lons_g      = arange(lonmin_g,lonmax_g+dlat,dlat)
LON_G,LAT_G = meshgrid(lons_g,lats_g) #THE SHAPE OF THIS IS A PROBLEM!!
# DEFINE SMALLER REGION
lonmin  = 120;
lonmax  = 130;
latmax  = -40;
latmin  = -50;
N       = 2; #THIS IS NxN SUB-GRID AVERAGE OF SMALLER REGION
ind  = argwhere( (LON_G>=lonmin) & (LON_G<=lonmax) & (LAT_G<=latmax) & (LAT_G>=latmin) )
ri   = ind[:,0]; 
ci   = ind[:,1];
LON = LON_G[ix_(ri,ci)]
LAT = LAT_G[ix_(ri,ci)]
LON = LON[1].reshape(5,5) #THIS IS STEP IS A RESULT OF LON_G,LAT_G BEING MIS-SHAPEN
LAT = LAT[1].reshape(5,5) #THIS IS STEP IS A RESULT OF LON_G,LAT_G BEING MIS-SHAPEN
# AVERAGE on NxN sub-grids such that
#INDEX GRID
# 
# Essentially we averaging each sub-grid within the domain, that is each 2x2, grid points
# IF the following is the domain:
#
#      (ln1,lt1)      (ln2,lt1)     (ln3,lt1)     (ln4,lt1)     (ln5,lt1)
#
#      (ln1,lt2)      (ln2,lt2)     (ln3,lt2)     (ln4,lt2)     (ln5,lt2)
#
#      (ln1,lt3)      (ln2,lt3)     (ln3,lt3)     (ln4,lt3)     (ln5,lt3)
#
#      (ln1,lt4)      (ln2,lt4)     (ln3,lt4)     (ln4,lt4)     (ln5,lt4)
#
#      (ln1,lt5)      (ln2,lt5)     (ln3,lt5)     (ln4,lt5)     (ln5,lt5)
#
# then the first sub-grid is:
#
#      (ln1,lt1)      (ln2,lt1) 
#
#      (ln1,lt2)      (ln2,lt2) 
#
# the next sub-grid is:
#
#      (ln2,lt1)     (ln3,lt1)
#
#      (ln2,lt2)     (ln3,lt2)
#
# So on, and so forth. If we associate each grid point with it's data then compute the average
# value of that sub-grid then we will have an `array', in this of 16 mean values, i.e.:
#
#      (ln1,lt1)      (ln2,lt1)     (ln3,lt1)     (ln4,lt1)     (ln5,lt1)
#               mean1          mean2         mean3         mean4
#      (ln1,lt2)      (ln2,lt2)     (ln3,lt2)     (ln4,lt2)     (ln5,lt2)
#               mean5          mean6         mean7         mean8
#      (ln1,lt3)      (ln2,lt3)     (ln3,lt3)     (ln4,lt3)     (ln5,lt3)
#               mean9          mean10        mean11        mean12
#      (ln1,lt4)      (ln2,lt4)     (ln3,lt4)     (ln4,lt4)     (ln5,lt4)
#               mean13         mean14        mean15        mean16
#      (ln1,lt5)      (ln2,lt5)     (ln3,lt5)     (ln4,lt5)     (ln5,lt5)
#
# We then take the mean of those means to get the mean of domain/region of each level.
# In doing the mean this way the over-lap in averaging towards the interior values provides
# more weight to those values and hence a more statistically significant mean for the
# the region.
#
TROP = trop[ix_(ri,ci)]
TROP = TROP[1].reshape(5,5) #Hmmm, I FEEL LIKE I'M REALLY NOT UNDERSTANDING PYTHON INDEXING
n,m = TROP.shape
TROP_BAR = average(split(average(split(TROP, m // N, axis=1), axis=-1), n // N, axis=1), axis=-1)
print(TROP_BAR)
OMEGA_BAR = zeros(12)
for i1 in range (0,11):
    oms = om[i1]
    OMS = OMS[ix_(ri,ci)]
    OMS = OMS[1].reshape(5,5)
    OMEGA_BAR[i1] = average(split(average(split(, m // N, axis=1), axis=-1), n // N, axis=1), axis=-1)
```

The average values I am getting are not making sense. So I would like to get averages that actually make sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Though I do not believe it is the most efficient way. I have figured out a solution that gives me the correct answer so I'll post it here (below). However, I would be curious if anyone has a more efficient solution, other than looping through the matrix. Again thanks in advance.

```
def gridavg(mat,n,k): 
    if (k > n): 
        return
    # row number of first cell in current 
    # sub-square of size k x k
    avg = zeros(15)
    for i in range(n - k + 1): 
        # column of first cell in current  
        # sub-square of size k x k 
        for j in range(n - k + 1): 
            # Calculate mean of current sub-square 
            for p in range(i, k + i): 
                for q in range(j, k + j):
                    avg[i+j+p+q] = mean(mat[p][q])
    return avg
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this code:

```
import numpy as np
def gridavg(testin):
    testin=np.array(testin)
    test_a=0.5*(testin[:-1,:]+testin[1:,:])
    testout=0.5*(test_a[:,:-1]+test_a[:,1:]);
    return testout
```

Unfortunately, this is only for 2x2 matrices, but it should be much faster as you would use NumPy arrays and matrix operations to average.

For more universal appoach, you could try this:

```
def gridavg(testin,n,k):
    testin=np.array(testin);
    from_end=1-k;
    if k>0:
        sum_a = None;
        for i0 in range(k):
            if sum_a is None:
                sum_a = np.array(testin[i0:(from_end+n),:]);
            else:
                sum_a = sum_a + testin[i0:(from_end+i0+n),:]
        sum_a = sum_a/float(k);

        sum_b = None;
        for j0 in range(k):
            if sum_b is None:
                sum_b = sum_a[:,j0:(from_end+n)];
            else:
                sum_b = sum_b + sum_a[:,j0:(from_end+j0+n)]
        testout = sum_b/float(k);
    return testout
```

I tried with random matrice and for k-values 2 and 3 seemed to work.